# Displaying and changing an external SVG background image

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to display and an external image inside an svg and then change it on button click. I can't get the background to show nor can I get it to change.

here is my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/bsp9601z/

```
<head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
</head>
<div id="slider"></div>
<button onclick="go()">change background</button>
<g id="backgroundImage">
  <image width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-2.jpg" /></g>


<svg width="792pt" height="612pt" viewBox="0 0 792 612" enable-background="new 0 0 792 612"
    version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >

</svg>
</svg>



function go(){

         var im = document.getElementById('backgroundImage');
                im.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href',     'http://demo.elmanawy.info/moraco/layout1/assets/images/portfolio/8.jpg');
                im.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','width', "100%");
                im.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','height', "100%");

}
```

Comment: I'm not too knowledgeable about svg but it seems like you're not using <g> correctly https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g

There's no such thing as <image> tag, only <img>. And you have an extra closing </svg>

Comment: @myfashionhub https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `<svg>` tags and selecting `<g>` rather than `<image>`

```html
<button onclick="go()">change background</button>
<svg>
<g id="backgroundImage">
  <image width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-2.jpg" />
</g>
</svg>
<script>
  function go() {
    var im = document.getElementById('backgroundImage').querySelector("image");
    im.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
    , 'xlink:href'
    , 'http://demo.elmanawy.info/moraco/layout1/assets/images/portfolio/8.jpg');
}

</script>
```

Comment: @RobertLongson Good catch. Since `width` and `height` do not change from initial values, it should not be necessary to re-set the properties to the same values. See updated post.